# Repetion of the same letter affect the function accum(s){ codewars

Tags: javascript

I can't figure out why instead of getting E-Ll-Lll-Eeee i'm getting just E-Ll-Ll-E.
its like the repetion of of letters (in this case E and L) affect the code.

The idea is that from an input like "hola" we get an output of "H-Oo-Lll-Aaaa"

```js
function accum(s) {
  let splitWord = s.split('');
  let rep = splitWord.map(letter => letter.repeat(splitWord.indexOf(letter) + 1));
  let cap = rep.map(word => word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1).toLowerCase());
  let uni = cap.join('-');

  return uni;
}

accum('hola');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is here: `splitWord.indexOf(letter)`. This will find *first* entry of your `letter` in array. Map function accepts second argument - index, which you need to use instead, like this:

```js
let rep = splitWord.map((letter, index) => letter.repeat(index + 1));
```

Also, it can be made a bit easier with [`.padEnd`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd):

```js
function accum(s) {
  let splitWord = s.split("");

  let rep = splitWord.map((letter, index) =>
    letter.toUpperCase().padEnd(index + 1, letter)
  );

  let uni = rep.join("-");

  return uni;
}
console.log(accum("elle"));
```